# How to get all the users and their permissions on a table or a view in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to get all the users and their permissions on a table or a view in snowflake.

Tried SHOW GRANTS ON VIEW db.schema.VIEW_NAME

Instead looking for a query which shows all the users and their permissions on all the views in a schema.

Comment: Can you try this SHOW GRANTS ON TABLE table_name;  and see if this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no simple way to do this, as it involves querying a number of different views and also requires recursive queries. This is a pretty good starting point: https://medium.com/hashmapinc/how-to-capture-snowflake-users-roles-and-grants-into-a-table-3ab3fd6cd0ce